# Stored Database Connection Variables In A File, But Marked As An Object

Tags: php, mysql

I have this database class to connect into MySQL :

```
private $db_host;
private $db_user;
private $db_pass;
private $db_name;

function __construct($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass, $db_name) {
    $this->db_host = $db_host;
    $this->db_user = $db_user;
    $this->db_pass = $db_pass;
    $this->db_name = $db_name;
}

public function connect(){
    if(!$this->con){
        $this->myconn = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
        if($this->myconn->connect_errno > 0){
            array_push($this->result,$this->myconn->connect_error);
            return false;
        }else{
            $this->con = true;
            return true;
        } 
    }else{  
        return true;
    }   
}
```

and I stored `$db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name` into `config.php` file.

whenever I want to connect into database, I use this code :

```
require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');
$product = new Product($db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name);
$product->connect();
```

well, unfortunately, that code produce this error log :

```
[06-Jan-2017 12:37:50 Asia/Jakarta] PHP Warning:  mysqli::mysqli() expects parameter 2 to be string, object given in /home/**/public_html/model/Database.class.php on line 39
```

Line 39 contains :

```
$this->myconn = new mysqli($this->db_host,$this->db_user,$this->db_pass,$this->db_name);
```

why `$db_server, $db_user, $db_password, $db_name` variables marked as an object? how to change it into string? so that error won't show up again.

thank you.

Comment: var_dump($db_user) and see what it gives

Comment: @e4c5 : it gives me this : string(15) "mydb_username"

Comment: show where the db_user comes from please

Comment: @e4c5 : it comes from this :

require_once ($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/config.php');

Comment: @e4c5 : I just update my post above. please check it out.

Comment: it doesn't show how $db_user variable is created

Comment: `$db_server = 'localhost';
$db_prefix = 'prefix';
$db_user = $db_prefix . '_dbuser';
$db_password = 'dbpassword123';
$db_name = $db_prefix . '_dbname';`

@e4c5 : like that.

Comment: you really have chosen an awfully complicated way of doing thins. What's wrong with just using mysqli_connect directly?

Comment: Your last comment still doesn't show how $db_user is built because now there is an unknown variable $prefix. You really really ought to simply this.